# update is not a function -> firebase/firestore writting data

Tags: javascript, angular, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting this error when i try to update data into my firebase:

Update() is not a function

My goal is to update the value of one boolean object that i have on my firebase.

Here is what i have :

```
firebase.firestore().object('/restaurant/' + key + '/loyaltyCard').update({loyaltyCard: false})
```

loyaltyCard is the value i want to change,but i cant seem to do that.

I watched some tutorials, read some firebase/firestore docs, but i am stuck now.

Comment: I've never seen `object()` as a method on `firebase.firestore()`.  Where did you find that?

Answer (score 1):

The update function is not called correctly. See example:

```
   firebase.firestore().collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
    .doc(DOC_ID)
    .update({loyaltyCard: false})
```